# Single Table Inheritance with Formtastic

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, single-table-inheritance

So I have two models that inherit from another as follows:

```
class OneTime < Step
  has_one :due_date
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :due_date
end

class Repeatable < Step
  has_many :due_dates
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :due_dates
end

class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goal
end
```

I also have another model that is nested within the subclasses:

```
class DueDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step
end
```

Then I have a form like this using formtastic:

```
= semantic_form_for [@goal, @step], :url => goal_step_path(@goal, @step), :html => { :class => "ajax"} do |f|
  = f.inputs :id => "step_#{@step.id}_description", :class => "description" do
    = f.input :description, :input_html => { :autofocus => "autofocus"}
  = f.semantic_fields_for :due_date do |due_date|
    = due_date.inputs :date_due, :as => :string, :input_html => { :class => "datepicker"}, :label => "Due Date"
  = f.buttons do
    = f.commit_button
```

The problem is that when I try to load that form I get the following error:

```
Showing /Users/dc/launchtools/app/views/steps/_form.html.haml where line #4 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: due_dates.one_time_id: SELECT  "due_dates".* FROM "due_dates" WHERE ("due_dates".one_time_id = 121) LIMIT 1
Extracted source (around line #4):
```

I've tried a lot of different things to fix it and nothing has worked. I have also searched through stackoverflow and google and haven't found anything that helps solve this problem. Maybe I am not approaching the problem correctly, but I need some direction. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass multiple arguments to `due_date.inputs` which it thinks are multiple fields, you want to use `due_date.input` (singular) instead, like so:

```
= due_date.input :date_due, :as => :string, :input_html => { :class => "datepicker"}, :label => "Due Date"
```

Comment: Since posting I have moved away from STI because my problem seemed to be better solved without it, but you are right about singular vs plural. I hadn't noticed that.